# Wrong syntax (MySQL, PHP)

Tags: php, mysql, sql

This line of code

```
$SQL = "SELECT * FROM stats ORDER BY Team WHERE Team='$teamval'";
```

is returning with the following MySQL error:

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to
your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE Team='OTT''
at line 1
```

I can't find anything wrong with the syntax, what's wrong with it?

Comment: [This is the relevant MySQL documentation from their manual about `SELECT` statement syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/select.html).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `ORDER BY` clause must appear after the `WHERE` clause. So, your query should, instead, be:

```
SELECT * FROM stats WHERE Team='$teamval' ORDER BY Team
```

Answer (score 1):

You have used in correct syntax of using order by before where clause , ORDER BY should be used at the end of query if you have used limit in your query then put order by before limit

```
SELECT * FROM stats  WHERE Team='$teamval' ORDER BY Team
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace:

```
$SQL="SELECT * FROM stats WHERE Team='$teamval' ORDER BY Team";
```